# Why I get a null or [ ] response from my server.js file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have been doing an example based on the [TV showTracker](http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-tv-show-tracker-using-angularjs-nodejs-and-mongodb/) and So far I couldn't get any shows into my website. I have been trying so hard to whether I have made a mistake but I still couldn't find anything. So How to I retrieve these information. I have stared this server.js and mongod in separate CMDs and gulp in another CMD I still couldn't get any of the shows. When I see the responses it will show a blank array "[]" like this. So any advice? Help would be most appreciated. (I have host the website yet, thought this would help also to my question). The error in the net debugger says api/shows/ - response = [ ]

Here is my server.jsrespone

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;



var showSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    name: String,
    airsDayOfWeek: String,
    airsTime: String,
    firstAired: Date,
    genre: [String],
    network: String,
    overview: String,
    rating: Number,
    ratingCount: Number,
    status: String,
    poster: String,
    subscribers: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
        }],
    episodes: [{
            season: Number,
            episodeNumber: Number,
            episodeName: String,
            firstAired: Date,
            overview: String
        }]
});


var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        email: { type: String, unique: true },
        password: String
    });

userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
}

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var Show = mongoose.model('Show', showSchema);

mongoose.connect('localhost');

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

app.get('/api/shows', function (req, res, next) {
    var query = Show.find();
    if (req.query.genre) {
        query.where({ genre: req.query.genre });
    } else if (req.query.alphabet) {
        query.where({ name: new RegExp('^' + '[' + req.query.alphabet + ']', 'i') });
    } else {
        query.limit(12);
    }
    query.exec(function (err, shows) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(shows);
    });
});

app.get('/api/shows/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    Show.findById(req.params.id, function (err, show) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(show);
    });
});

app.post('/api/shows', function (req, res, next) {
    var apiKey = 'E36B52F7E036AFF3';
    var seriesName = req.body.showName
    .toLowerCase()
    .replace(/ /g, '_')
    .replace(/[^\w-]+/g, '');
    var parser = xml2js.Parser({
        explicitArray: false,
        normalizeTags: true

    });

    async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            request.get('http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=' + seriesName, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) return next(error);
                parser.parseString(body, function (err, result) {
                    if (!result.data.series) {
                        return res.send(404, { message: req.body.showName + ' was not found.' });
                    }
                    var seriesId = result.data.series.seriesid || result.data.series[0].seriesid;
                    callback(err, seriesId);
                });
            });
        },
        function (seriesId, callback) {
            request.get('http://thetvdb.com/api' + apiKey + '/series/' + seriesId + '/all/en.xml', function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) return next(error);
                parser.parseString(body, function (err, result) {
                    var series = result.data.series;
                    var episodes = result.data.episode;
                    var show = new Show({
                        _id: series.id,
                        name: series.seriesname,
                        airsDayOfWeek: series.airs_dayofweek,
                        airsTime: series.airs_time,
                        firstAired: series.firstaired,
                        genre: series.genre.split('|').filter(Boolean),
                        network: series.network,
                        overview: series.overview,
                        rating: series.rating,
                        ratingCount: series.ratingcount,
                        runtime: series.runtime,
                        status: series.status,
                        poster: series.poster,
                        episodes: []
                    });
                    _.each(episodes, function (episode) {
                        show.episodes.push({
                            season: episode.seasonnumber,
                            episodeNumber: episode.episodenumber,
                            episodeName: episode.episodename,
                            firstAired: episode.firstaired,
                            overview: episode.overview
                        });
                    });
                    callback(err, show);
                });
            });
        },
        function (show, callback) {
            var url = 'http://thetvdb.com/banners/' + show.poster;
            request({ url: url, encoding: null }, function (error, response, body) {
                show.poster = 'data:' + response.headers['content-type'] + ';base64,' + body.toString('base64');
                callback(error, show);
            });
        }
    ], function (err, show) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        show.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                if (err.code == 11000) {
                    return res.send(409, { message: show.name + ' already exists.' });
                }
                return next(err);

            }
            res.send(200);
        });
    });
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) next();
    else res.send(401);
};

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
        res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(req.user));
    }
    next();
});



app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
})

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.send(500, { message: err.message });
});
```

Comment: step 1: reduce your code to an [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The process of doing this is basic prep when asking these kinds of questions, and *usually* lets you discover discover what's wrong in the process, so you never even have to ask your question. And then in case you don't find the problem, you have a much better, smaller, accurate piece of code to ask questions about.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I blame the blog post this is linked to, as it basically constructs the whole listing in a single file. But based on the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33472211/how-to-retreive-data-from-thetvdb-com) from the OP and the lack of detail and explanation in the original post that there is no data at all, or at least it's not in the same collection or database that this code is trying to connect to.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So sorry, I'm bit desperate to get the answers. I been finding answers for two days not moving forward I still can't see what the error is, not with their online database, I' ve checked that.

Comment: You should at the very least remove all the routes that aren't involved in the error you're seeing, and explain how people who are not you can test this. The most obvious recommendation, however, would be "don't ask this here, first ask it over on the [official project](https://github.com/sahat/tvshow-tracker)", because obviously they are by far the most qualified to answer your question.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'll email him though he'll ever reply.

Comment: Rather than emailing, just file an issue on the project's issue tracker, outlining your problem (and then you can even put that link in your post to show that you're trying that in addition to asking SO for help). Email is very much not the right choice here.

Comment: Yes I'll do that. Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var query = Show.find();` in /api/shows to

```
var query  = Show.find(function(err, showdata){
    // all the checking and the res.send(shows) goes here
})
```

Just wait for data and do all the operation(asynchronous)

Comment: It still didn't work. same with even not a single error.

Comment: I thinks the problem is with the code like said by the Blakes Seven, Even if you do you still can't find a way to connect it

Answer (score 0):

OK Guys, I finally found the answer to the question. It's nothing wrong with the script (server.js). It is because I think it cannot hold the data in the database (`'localhost:27017/test'`). That is why maybe I'm getting a null response from the TVDB API. Once I changed my database and connect strings to (

> `'mongodb://nixsiow:abcd1234@ds027479.mongolab.com:27479/nixshowtrackrapp'`
>   , It worked like a charm.

So maybe my answer may not explain this properly, or you can look for more details in stack overflow. Thanks for the help guys. I hope that this will help who try to do this tutorial and get stuck on this step.

So final Answer:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://nixsiow:abcd1234@ds027479.mongolab.com:27479/nixshowtrackrapp');

var agenda = require('agenda')({ db: { address: 'mongodb://nixsiow:abcd1234@ds027479.mongolab.com:27479/nixshowtrackrapp'  } });
```

Also [Nixsow's website](http://code.nixsiow.com/) may have a help, it is the most recent update that I found for this tutorial.